# problem with .requestMatchers().permitAll()

Tags: java, spring-security

I've finally decided to create an account on this platform because I couldn't find a solution to my problem. I'm not advanced in Java and I'm having trouble with SecurityFilterChain. I want the main "home" page to be visible to everyone without logging in, but it keeps redirecting me to the login page. I've mapped the access points I need and I've been working on it for a while now.

Perhaps someone can spot where the problem is.

Using Spring boot 3.0.2

CODE:

```
package xxxxxxxxxxxxx

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
                .password(encoder.encode("pass"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        UserDetails user1 = User.withUsername("user1")
                .password(encoder.encode("pass1"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin,user1);
    }

    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/item/**")
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().and().build();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Comment: What page are you accessing which redirects you?

Comment: `SecurityFilterChain`  should be a bean... Add `@Bean` above the `securityFilterChain(..)` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `@Bean` annotation from the `SecurityFilterChain` method. It could be a problem.

I let you this code. If you use this you can reach all pages after login, and you can reach home page before login.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll());
    return http.build();
  }
```